# Could this be my water pressure reducing valve?

Tags: water-pressure

Can’t seem to locate it. My house was built in 1986 on a slab.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Nope.  That appears to be the shutoff for the cold water supply to the water heater.

A PRV looks like this:

[image]

it is sometimes buried inside a wall or a vault outside.  Look around for the main water shutoff for the house - it should be close to that.  A couple of places I have lived didn't even have one.

Comment: If municipal pressure is not too high, you don't need one. If you are on a well, you don't need one.